# Creating columns based off of OrderID Items

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I am working with a basic table, and am curious if there is any possibility to have  everything for my id to show on the same row? Below I have shown an example of my current query and the output, along with how I'd like to see the output be shown.

Select OrderID, Item, Quantity, Location from samples order by OrderID

```
-----------------------------------
|OrderID | Item | Weight | Location|
-----------------------------------
    1     apple    4.2        Wi
    1     banana   2.1        Wi
    2     orange   1          Mi
    3     apple    1.8        Mn
    3     grape    .5         Mn
```

I would like to see it export like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------
|OrderID | Apple | Banana | Orange | Grape | Location|
------------------------------------------------------
    1      4.2      2.1                         Wi
    2                          1                Mi
    3      1.8                        .5        Mn
```

Comment: What if apple's location is different than banana's location for id 1?

Comment: Is the `.2` in your expected result a typo ?

Comment: @Tony, Yes sorry.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Perhaps take the first location(1 location) if that were to ever happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to need conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT
    OrderID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN item = 'apple' THEN weight END) Apple,
    MAX(CASE WHEN item = 'banana' THEN weight END) Banana,
    MAX(CASE WHEN item = 'orange' THEN weight END) Orange,
    MAX(CASE WHEN item = 'grape' THEN weight END) Grape
    Location
FROM samples
GROUP BY OrderID, Location
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
SELECT OrderID,case when item = Apple then weight end as apple,case when item = Banana then weight end as Banana,case when item = Orange then weight end as orange,...,
location from yourtable